# stretch, scale, or double up an array with numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was wondering if there is a numpy function to "stretch" an array along a specific axis
like the following:

`a =[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]`

to

`a = [[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4],[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]]`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]])
```

First possibility:

```
a.repeat(2, axis=1)
```

or the second:

```
np.kron(a, [1,1])
```

Both returning:

```
array([[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4],
       [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]])
```